# Matlab overlay imagesc on binary image

Tags: matlab

I am trying to overlay an imagesc image on top of a binary image. I searched for it online, but no luck. Below is my code:

```
figure;
imshow(BW4);
hold on
imagesc(image2,'AlphaData',0.5); axis equal; axis tight; axis off;
myColorMap = jet(256);
myColorMap(1,:) = 0;
colormap(myColorMap); colorbar;
hold off
```

The output what I am getting looks like below image on right, instead of the jet colormap lines on top of white color. Can someone help me to fix this issue? I appreciate your time and effort.

Thanks,

Binary image

[image: Binary image]

Jet image

[image: Jet image]

Result what I am getting which I do not want

[image: Result what I am getting which I do not want]

Comment: there are few problems here. Check `axis ij` and `axis xy` in the docs to see the difference between iimshow and imgagesc axes and how to change that. Also, define overlay? if you overlay it you get the second one, no?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I didn't get what overlay you are referring to? Would you please elaborate it?

Comment: NO, you are referring to overlay, its in the title of your question.  what do you want to overlay? the color over the white?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to overlay?  I'm confused with your problem statement

Comment: So is the image labeled "Jet image" what you are trying to get? Or is that your input image `image2`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have a binary image and I want the jet image on top of it. yes, the color over white.

Comment: @rayryeng I want imagesc (jet image) on a binary image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, yes, if I do not use imshow(BW4). I will get the "Jet image" as shown. What I want is the jet image on top of the binary image. In other words, I want the jet image with the white background as shown in binary image.

Comment: @PManjunatha That doesn't make sense.  You will only get two colours due to the binary image.

Comment: @rayryeng, yes that is what I am getting as in the last image. What I want is "jet image" on the white object as shown in the first image. so technically, the jet image will have the white background.

Comment: Provide the original "jet" image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we first read your bw data `a` and create some jet image `b` which is some nxm matrix of intensities:

```
 a=rgb2gray(imread('fFIG2.png'));
 a=a==max(a(:)); 
 a=a>0; % now it is binary

% make jet data with 0 being it's minimal value
b=(imresize(peaks(100),size(a))).*a ;
b=b.*(b>0);
```

Now we normalize the data in `b` between 0 and 1 and make an RGB array out of it. The we'll create a mask and assign white to it...

```
cmap=[0,0,0;jet(255)]; % set the colormap to be always black and jet

% normalize from nxm matrix to nxmx3 rgb values
c=b;
c=round( ((c-min(c(:)) )/(max(c(:))-min(c(:))))*(length(cmap)-1)+1);
im=reshape(cmap(c(:),:),[size(c),3]);

% get the mask for all pixels that are in a but are zero in b
bw2=repmat( (a>0 & b==0),[1 1 3]);
im(bw2)=1; % assign this pixels with rgb=white
imagesc(im)
```

[image]

Comment: But this approach will make everything black background. What I want is when I put the jet image on top of the binary image, I should get the white background. It is like overlaying imagesc plot on binary image. In other words, the black region surrounding the lines in imagesc plot should be white.

Comment: I still dont understand. You want to overlay the jet on top of a BW image and be able to see them independently? i.e. to see jet+white+black in the image?

Comment: Exactly, the background will be black, and I want the jet image on the white background of the binary image.

Comment: ok, this assumes that the jet image also has zeros (black) in it and that the white part is a mask to show everything in that area? I'll edit my answer...

Comment: quick question before, does the jet image always have positive values or can they be anything? in other words, is the color black always zero?

Comment: Yes, the jet image will be always positive. Is the color black always zero? It is made to zero because I needed a black background. Sometime for the sake of publication the background might need to be white.

Comment: I did, thanks for the help! It works for both black and white background!