# How to make NaN and Zeros transparent using imagesc function in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, maps, transparency

I have a matrix `hist2` which contains a lot of `NaN` and zeros values. I displayed its values on a map. However, my problem is that `NaN` and zeros get dark blue color, and I'd like them to have no color at all, to be completely transparent.

I have tried different things:

1. ```
   imAlpha = ones(size(hist2));
   imAlpha(isnan(hist2)) = 0;
   im = imagesc(hist2,'AlphaData',imAlpha);
   set(gca,'color',[1 1 1]);
   ```
2. ```
   im.AlphaDataMapping = 'none';
   im.FaceAlpha = 'texturemap';
   alpha(im,double(~isnan(hist2)));
   ```

Unfortunately, none of these worked. I don't have other ideas.

The following code output is the map below:

```
ax = worldmap([0 45],[-110 -30])
land = shaperead('landareas.shp', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(land, 'FaceColor', [0.15 0.5 0.15])
xgrid = minx:gridres:maxx;
ygrid = miny:gridres:maxy;
im = imagesc(xgrid,ygrid,hist2/(gridres^2),'AlphaData',imAlpha);
colorbar
uistack(im,'bottom')
hold on 
xlabel('Longitude (E)')
ylabel('Latitude (N)')
drawnow
```

[image: output]

Later, I successfully turn the blue area to white - but it was still not transparent. I'd like the dark blue area to have no color.

Comment: so is the image attached what you want ? what is the total thing you are after?

Comment: look at my answer here and tell me if it helps... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389329/matlab-overlay-imagesc-on-binary-image/49395079#49395079

Comment: Hi bla, I want the dark blue to have no color at all, so later the land will be on the bottom covered only by the data. I didn't quite understand your answer link. Thanks.

Comment: what toolbox are you using to map the data?

Comment: I have mapping toolbox R2017a.

Comment: please write a minimal code that creates an image like that so we can answer

Comment: Ok. I will add a code.